# Angular property binding isn't working properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created this table:
[image]

What I tried to do: 
Click on "Change 1 jour Top Management Value" above the table and change the value of the cell1 Row1. But, I couldn't.

> Here's the html code:

```
   <button (click)="DisplayReceivedDataValues()">Change 1 jour Top Management Value</button>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card-plain">
              <div class="header">
                <div class="typo-line">
                  <h4 class="text-center text-info">
                    TOTAL
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Profile</th>
                      <th scope="row" *ngFor="let cell of tableData1.headerRow">
                        {{ cell }}
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{ tableData1.leftSideColumn[0] }}</th>
                      <td >{{unJourValues[0][0]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxTroisJoursValues[0][0]}}</td>
                      <td >{{quatreCinqJoursValues[0][0]}}</td>
                      <td >{{uneSemaineValues[0][0]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxSemainesValues[0][0]}}</td>
                      <td >{{unMoisPlusValues[0][0]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{ tableData1.leftSideColumn[1] }}</th>
                      <td >{{unJourValues[0][1]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxTroisJoursValues[0][1]}}</td>
                      <td >{{quatreCinqJoursValues[0][1]}}</td>
                      <td >{{uneSemaineValues[0][1]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxSemainesValues[0][1]}}</td>
                      <td >{{unMoisPlusValues[0][1]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{ tableData1.leftSideColumn[2] }}</th>
                      <td >{{unJourValues[0][2]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxTroisJoursValues[0][2]}}</td>
                      <td >{{quatreCinqJoursValues[0][2]}}</td>
                      <td >{{uneSemaineValues[0][2]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxSemainesValues[0][2]}}</td>
                      <td >{{unMoisPlusValues[0][2]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{ tableData1.leftSideColumn[3] }}</th>
                      <td >{{unJourValues[0][3]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxTroisJoursValues[0][3]}}</td>
                      <td >{{quatreCinqJoursValues[0][3]}}</td>
                      <td >{{uneSemaineValues[0][3]}}</td>
                      <td >{{deuxSemainesValues[0][3]}}</td>
                      <td >{{unMoisPlusValues[0][3]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

> DisplayReceivedDataValues defintion:

```
 DisplayReceivedDataValues(){
    this.unJourValues[0][0]=15
    console.log('unJourValues: ', this.unJourValues[0][0]);
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea why isn't the new value 15 isn't displayed in the first cell in the first row?
Shouldn't property binding make this work??

Answer (score 0):

If you mutate the array, Angular doesn't detect the change. Replace

```
    this.unJourValues[0][0]=15
```

with something like

```
    this.unJourValues = this.unJourValues.map((row, index) => index === 0
        ? /* new values here */
        : row);
```

Comment: Can you explain why doesn't Angular detect the change?

Comment: It does a shallow check of properties like `unJourValues`. If the reference is the same, it assumes it's the same object.